# It doesn't displayed \section name, number... at header in \tcolorbox

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, tcolorbox

I am trying about section's in `tcolorbox`.
My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=6cm,marginparsep=.5cm,
outer=7.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,hooks,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mhsetup}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\nouppercase{Section \thesection{}}\quad\textcolor{orange}{$\blacksquare$}\quad}\textit{\rightmark}\quad\quad\textcolor{blue}{\textbf\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf\thepage}\textbf{\quad\quad\nouppercase{Chapter{ }\thechapter\quad\textcolor{orange}{$\blacksquare$}\quad}}\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,interior style={left color=red!20!yellow,right color=black!40!white},leftrule=0mm,frame hidden,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=-1mm,bottom=1mm,arc=2mm]\textit{\section{Coulomb’s Law}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,interior style={left color=red!20!yellow,right color=black!40!white},leftrule=0mm,frame hidden,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=-1mm,bottom=1mm,arc=2mm]\textit{\section{Heron's Law}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-7]
\section{Leva's Law}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

But, it doesn't display `\section` name, number... at header in `\tcolorbox`. In the other hand it does display `\section` name, number... at header in not `\tcolorbox`. That is, In the 3. page, section information is not displayed.

In the `\section{Leva's Law}` working but other sections not working. It may be the solution this problem?

...EDITED...
Page 3 and page 4 good working.

[image]

But I wrote @Christian Hupfer's codes, displayed following the picture. **Section 1.10** is not *Test* section.

[image]

Comment: The displayed headers on the pages originate from your setup of `\fancy....` etc. `tcolorbox` has no information your section titles ahead, you must choose another way, e.g. via nameref!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution uses a label for each section inside a `tcolorbox`, calling the title with `\nameref*{}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}%



\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\overhanglength}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\setlength{\overhanglength}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhanglength}{\marginparsep}
\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@mparswitch}\AND\boolean{@twoside}}
{\fancyhfoffset[RE,RO]{\overhanglength}}
{\fancyhfoffset[LE,RO]{\overhanglength}}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} 
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}{%
\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{\thepage\quad\S\quad\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}%
\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\S\quad\thepage}}%
}{
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\thepage}%
}
\makeatother
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@parbox@use@false{%
\def\@parboxrestore{\linewidth\hsize\let\@parboxrestore=\tcb@parboxrestore}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false,title=\nameref*{section::number_one}]
\section{This section title is shown!} \label{section::number_one}%
abc\par cde
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Test} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\nameref*{section::2}]%
\section{This section title is also shown!} \label{section::2}%
abc\par cde
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hupher, your source code it is not working in my computer. In the line `\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false,title=\nameref*{section::number_one}]` , it's take error `Missing $ inserted` . I'm erasing the asterix then code is working but not exactly. Always **1.2 Test** writing in header. I did edited my question, added the about picture. I hope you good work.

Comment: My code works as expected. There are no error messages. Do you have the latest TexLive distribution? I update every day. If you edit your question, I can't do anything more, since you added not more code, especially about section numbers being 1.10 etc. while there are just three sections in your example

Comment: Dear @Christian Hupfer, up to now I am grateful for you for all your helps. I am so sorry I got to spend your working time. I edited my question, because; it be clearly. I had no bad intention, indeed. Anymore, both I will work yours code and I will look answer or later again question. (Ubuntu12.04LTS - LaTeXila 2.4.0)

Comment: @Özgür: Sorry, I will look later on... I have been busy on other stuff

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck your stuff. No problem.

Comment: After updating it worked.